Maven Serenity: Failed to resolve the class file version of the current VM: Unknown Java version: 0
I am currently trying to set up a project, but I keep running into this issue. I am currently using maven 3.9.6 and Java 22.0.1.
I can provide more info if needed, right now I have no idea what to provide.
I have made sure everything in Intellij is set to java 22. In the POM file I have also set the Java version to be 22 in source and target.
I have also tried running individual scripts not related to the project in the project files and they run with not issue.
enter image description here
enter image description here

Java class version for jdk 22 is 66.
Try configuring the class version in intellij.

@AjajAli How do I go about doing that? Sorry I am pretty new to Java as a whole.

Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need.
As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the
How to Ask page for help clarifying this question. Include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to
reproduce the issue. See also How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Also don't use images for text information., Please copy or type the text into the question. Reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text. Code or sample data in images can't be copied and pasted in order to search about a problem or reproduce it. For more details read the Meta FAQ entry Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?
